# Text overflow issue with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I was wondering how to make the text in a highcharts legend clip or make an ellipsis after certain amount of characters. I know that I can set the legend style but not sure how to make it so that it works in this situation

http://jsfiddle.net/t96zj1yr/

```
'hidden',$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            marginBottom: 120,
            width: 500
        },

        legend: {
            itemWidth: 100,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#7CB57C',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                width: '70px',
                textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                overflow: "hidden",
                whiteSpace: "nowrap"
            },
            useHTML: true
        },

        series: [{
            data: [6, 4, 2],
            name: 'Firstasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf'
        }, {
            data: [7, 3, 2],
            name: 'Second'
        }, {
            data: [9, 4, 8],
            name: 'Third'
        }, {
            data: [1, 2, 6],
            name: 'Fourth'
        }, {
            data: [4, 6, 4],
            name: 'Fifth'
        }, {
            data: [1, 2, 7],
            name: 'Sixth'
        }, {
            data: [4, 2, 5],
            name: 'Seventh'
        }, {
            data: [8, 3, 2],
            name: 'Eighth'
        }, {
            data: [4, 5, 6],
            name: 'Ninth'
        }]
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `maxWidth: '70px'` instead of `width: '70px'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the item style of the legend to include

```
max-width: 10ch;
```

Which should approximate a number of characters

Edit: 
You can use Jquery to edit the contents of the spans based on the number of characters in its contents. This should add ellipsis for anything longer than 10 characters after the 10th character.

```
$('.highcharts-legend-item').find('span').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  if(content.length > 10)
  {
      $(this).html(content.substring(0, 10) + "...");
  }
});
```

Give this a whirl - you'll just need to change the character limits to desired length. Seems to be working fine

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Sorry I posted wrong fiddle... This works for text that have some white space, do you know if it is possible to make it work with text that does not have whitespace like in the updated fiddle?

Comment: Ah, you'll probably need to write a script that changes the HTML contents of the Legend Spans when the length is greater than a certain number of characters.... I'll update my answer in a moment with a quick sample